# How can I upgrade yarn on Azure Web Service and make yarn workspaces work

Tags: node.js, azure, yarnpkg, azure-web-app-service, yarn-workspaces

I cannot make yarn workspaces work on Azure Web Service and I cannot upgrade yarn.

I have an application deployed as Azure Web Service. It uses yarn workspaces. Unfortunately during `yarn install` the error occurs

```
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/@gsx/common'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/site/wwwroot/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I read that upgrading the yarn can solve the problem. Azure by default comes with yarn 1.6.0.

I have `deploy.sh` file in my repository, so I can customize the deployment process. I would like to add command to upgrade yarn.

I tried to achieve it in two ways:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Both of them fails. In the first situation I get a message that I do not have enough permissions. In the second one the logs say that there is no command `sudo`.

Do you have an idea, how can I upgrade yarn?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/stefangordon/kudu-yarn) repo and give it a try. All you'd have to do is copy the `deploy.cmd` and `.deployment` files from the above repo to yours, which would make Kudu use this script instead of the default one. Hope this helps.